# What do 'spile' and 'bung' mean in this sentence written by Thoreau?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, nouns

In [A Plea for Captain John Brown](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2567/pg2567-images.html), Thoreau writes:

> What though he did not belong to your clique! Though you may not approve of his method or his principles, recognize his magnanimity. Would you not like to claim kindredship with him in that, though in no other thing he is like, or likely, to you? Do you think that you would lose your reputation so? What you lost at the [spile](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spile), you would gain at the [bung](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bung#Noun).

I have looked *spile* and *bung* in a dictionary, yet their meaning remains unclear to me in this sentence. What do these words mean here?

Comment: A far more common expression for this meaning (in BrE, at least) is [***It's swings and roundabouts***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/swings-and-roundabouts)  - *If you say that a situation is **swings and roundabouts**, you mean that there are as many gains as there are losses.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Just to add that I'm a native AmEng speaker, and have only heard "swings and roundabouts" on British shows. I also, until five minutes ago, had no idea what it meant. If I were explaining my newly-gained knowledge to another AmEng speaker, I'd probably say "you win some, you lose some" (even though it's not quite the same).

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: It's [*six of one and half-a-dozen of the other*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/six-of-one-and-half-a-dozen-of-the-other) - but again, even if Americans do say that (and I suspect they don't often, anyway) it's yet another a slightly different meaning.

Comment: For what it's worth (which isn't much, this is the very definition of 'anecdotal'), I was raised a (mostly) AmE speaker but I've spent around 8 years in total living in the UK and have never even heard of this phrase, @FumbleFingers. Perhaps it has some sort of regional and/or generational variation? I am familiar with both "you win some, you lose some" and "six of one..."

Comment: @terdon: Have a look at [this usage chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%27s+swings+and+roundabouts%2Cwin+some+you+lose+some&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) - if you combined all the upper and lower case, ***it's swings and roundabouts*** would be more common than ***win some you lose some*** (for which case doesn't matter, because there'll be hardly any relevant instances that don't start with ***you*** or ***You***). Toggling BrE / AmE makes quite a bit of difference, though.

Comment: @terdon - Maybe that's a difference between interacting day-to-day with people and consuming media. Performers are going to go for more vivid and entertaining language than the person-in-the-street. Also, thinking more about it, probably 60% of the times I've heard "swings and roundabouts" said, it's been from David Mitchell.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC more likely I just haven't happened to come across it. As I said, my "evidence" is very, very anecdotal and just because my British friends haven't happened to use the phrase around me isn't really enough evidence to conclude anything. FF's NGRAM is far more conclusive and seems to prove me wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thoreau was a writer who was also a naturalist, an environmentalist.

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_David_Thoreau)
> Thoreau (July 12, 1817 – May 6, 1862) was an American naturalist, essayist, poet, and philosopher.

In this prose he is alluding to the practice of tapping trees to obtain sugary syrup (for direct use or for fermentation). In North America he would have been particularly familiar with the tapping of maples.

> [Tap my Trees](https://tapmytrees.com/tap-tree/)
> ...
> *Inserting the Spile:
> Clear any wood shavings from the edge of the hole. Insert the spile into the loop on the hook (hook facing outward), and then insert the spile into the tap hole. Gently tap the spile into the tree with a hammer (do not pound the spile into the tree, as this may cause the wood to split). If the sap is flowing, you should immediately see sap dripping from the spile.*

As is clear from these instructions, the spile is an inserted spout.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spile)
> *spile*
> a spout inserted in a tree to draw off sap

A bung is a stopper used to stop the flow from a cask

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bung)
> *bung*:
> the stopper especially in the bunghole of a cask

The syrup lost from the tree at the spile would in those days have been collected or stored in cask. When the bung was taken from the cask, the syrup would be regained by the tapper.

So Thoreau seems to suggest that whatever is seemingly lost by association with Brown would be regained by the association with his magnanimity.

Comment: This is a much better answer!

Comment: Expanding on the MW interpretation: a "bung" is a plug inserted in a hole in a barrel. A "spile" or "spile pin" is inserted through a hole in a bung, and may be removed to reduce pressure and then reinserted. So very freely, the overall meaning is similar to the Biblical splinter vs beam in somebody's eye.

Comment: This is just pure folk etymology. Spiles were used to tap casks long before they were ever used to tap a maple tree. So, a spile is used to remove wine from a cask; the bung to close the cask up. You're trying to over-complicate it.

Answer (score 8):

This is without doubt a variant of a standard image  which terms vary as to the form of the words or the reference used to identify the concept, but which is always the same. According to the reference below it could be found as early as 1642.

> ([Academic Dictionaries and Encyclopedias](https://proverbs_new.en-academic.com/2236/spare_at_the_spigot%2C_and_let_out_at_the_bung-hole))  spare at the spigot, and let out at the bung-hole

"Spigot" is a synonym for "spile"

> (SOED) **spile** A small wooden peg or plug; a spigot. (Chiefly *Sc. & dial*)

> (SOED) **spigot** A small peg or plug inserted into the vent-hole of a barrel or cask.

> (SOED) **bung** **1** A stopper, *esp.* a large cork for stopping a hole in a cask. **2** *transf* = *bung-hole* below *obs.* exc. *dial*
> **bung-hole** a hole in a cask for filling and emptyng it.

It means that in considering the loss that you incur from a particular action you should consider the gain that is also derived from it and that makes up for the loss.

Comment: A number of people in the UK will be familiar with these concepts thanks to the chain of pubs branded "Tap and Spile". Although I believe most of them are gone now.